# Startup issue in dual boot: GRUB has disappeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo, startup

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04 dual booted on my laptop (Lenovo T14 Gen 2 Intel). I'm mostly on Ubuntu but today had to use Office so I switched to Windows. I installed the updates and restarted the system, but it now goes directly to Windows. Apparently boot priority changed so that "Windows Bootloader" is at the top. In which order should I rearrange the priority?
Attached goes the pic of the present boot priority. [image]

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu/grub on major updates, reset boot order for them to be first. And Windows may update UEFI or change some other UEFI settings. Best to review to be sure settings are still the same. And Windows often turns fast start up back on in Windows. You may be able to boot a "fallback" or drive boot entry. If Ubuntu in the NVMe drive, try booting it. That entry in UEFI is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Otherwise boot live installer and post `sudo efibootmgr -v`.

Answer (score -1):

When I did the same on my HP laptop I found that I had to install Ubuntu first. With GParted I did the following:

1. create a blank GPT partition;
2. set one partition of FAT32 (minimum of 33mb) for grub;
3. set one EFI partition (I use 512Mb);
4. finally create whatever usable partitions you wish to use (at the minimum, one NTFS partition for Windows and one EXT4 for Ubuntu)

If you need to use a swap file, make sure to use, at the minimum, the total size of your memory on your machine.

Make sure to set the flags on the EFI partition (select esp and the other flag will automatically be selected) and the grub partition (boot). This will make it so that it will boot directly into the grub instead of having to use the Windows Boot Manager to select the OS which can be tricky at best and isn't conducive to more than one OS.

Good Luck